# Compare 2 css style attributes in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Very quick one for you. So I want to compare 2 css style attributes. Lets say margin-left. If margin-left is smaller then 500px I dont want to do anything, if its higher I want to add another 500px margin.

For those asking this is for image slider... :)

I've tried

```
$('.slider-nav .left').click(function(){
        if($('.slide li').css('margin-left') < '500px'){
            // Do Nothing
        } else {
            $('.slide li').animate({'margin-left': '-=500px'}, animationSpeed);


}
    });
```

I know this isnt right but I can't find another way to do it. Could somebody atleast point me to the right direction?

Comment: if($('.slide li').css('margin-left') >= '500px')?

Comment: Ty it worked. Answer the question so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "negate" the comparison operator to get what you want directly,e.g.

```
$('.slider-nav .left').click(function(){
    if($('.slide li').css('margin-left') >= '500px'){
        $('.slide li').animate({'margin-left': '-=500px'}, animationSpeed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First couple of lines as you already have, then:-

```
    } 
    else {
        $('.slide li').css('margin-left', '1000px');
    }
```

Comment: what is this supposed to do?